# jQuery - change checkbox state

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I read many topics here about it, but can't understand why my code does not work

I have

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxList("CategoryCheckboxes", values, labels, null)%>
```

result of HTML:

```
<input id="CategoryCheckboxes" name="CategoryCheckboxes" type="checkbox" value="1" />(IN) Insight

<BR /><input id="CategoryCheckboxes" name="CategoryCheckboxes" type="checkbox" value="11" />CBT (Computer Based Testing)

<BR /><input id="CategoryCheckboxes" name="CategoryCheckboxes" type="checkbox" value="14" />NG Ideas Module

<BR /><input id="CategoryCheckboxes" name="CategoryCheckboxes" type="checkbox" value="12" />Typing Test



<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var isModified = false;

    function changed() {
        //isModified = true;
        alert('a');
    }

    function LeavePage() {
        if (isModified) {
            return 'Data is modified. Do you want to save it?';
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('checkbox').change(changed);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, there isn't any tags called `checkbox`. You have an input with the type `checkbox`

Use ([**example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qt6CD/))

```
$(':checkbox')
```